# MySQL SQL rules for user

Tags: security, mysql, database, sql-server

Let's say I have a MySQL database, with a table session_data containing:

```
| ID | SESSION_KEY | SECRET_DATA
| 100| ABCDEFGHIJK | bankAccountNumber=123123
```

Normally, users would have to authenticate with their session key `ABCDEFGHIJK`, before the web application would charge their bank account number. In other words, the only time the application would have a legitimate reason for needing the `bankAccountNumber` is if a valid session key is supplied.

eg.

```
SELECT `SECRET_DATA` FROM session_data WHERE `SESSION_KEY` = 'ABCDEFGHIJK' LIMIT 1;
```

Thus, I know if someone tried to do `SELECT`SECRET_DATA`FROM session_data;` or `SELECT * from session_data;` it's probably a malicious user who somehow found a hole in my application.

(this is a hypothetical example and I do not actually do this.)

So, to limit the amount of damage they can do, I would like to add a filter to my MySQL database.

Thus, assuming an attacker managed to get my application's SQL credentials, the MySQL database would itself reject any query for `SECRET_DATA` that was not accompanied by any `SESSION_KEY`. The credentials would still be useless to an attacker trying to gain information, since he wouldn't be able to query the database and have it return any useful information without submitting a `SESSION_KEY`, and if he submitted an invalid `SESSION_KEY`, there'd simply not be any resultant rows (and if he submitted a valid `SESSION_KEY`, he might as well just have used my application's publicly available interface anyways and authenticate as a legitimate user).

How would I implement such a filter, short of writing a stored procedure (which at this point is unfeasible)? I've heard of MySQL Proxy, but I'm not too sure if it's capable of doing this.

Comment: It would be a significant undertaking, rather unfeasible at this point, to rewrite an application to use stored procedures...

Comment: If the attacker has your credentials, even with this constraint, they could simply `select SESSION_KEY from session_data` and then go to town from there. I think you will be better served investing your energy in securing the system to prevent compromised access to the database more generally.

Comment: I wanted to do this more of as an additional measure.
But even for that, if I could filter queries, I would know... My application will never have a legitimate reason to need to fetch session keys from the database either, so that wouldn't be an 'allowed query' either.